# Are questions about Trial and Beta on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Obviously unreleased games are off-topic, because there's no way to know what the answer will be until the game is released. This can include trial and beta, because while I can play the game now, the details may change upon official release.

However, if I'm asking about the trial/beta *specifically* - e.g. "how do I do (X) in the beta of (game)", is that on topic?

Comment: tl;dr- Yes, it's on topic.